# Money back because of the cancelled flight with Onur Air

Tags: air-travel, cancellations, refunds

3 weeks ago I bought a two-way ticket Cologne-Istanbul-Cologne from Onur-Air. Yesterday I received an e-mail that the second flight got cancelled. Do I have a right to ask for a refund for both tickets and not just one? Has anyone else been in such a situation?

UPD: I called an operator and asked to get a refund for both tickets, that's what I needed the most and also I bought them together at once. The operator was kind and told that I will receive the refund in 3-5 days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been in the same situation with an other airline, one that sells one way only tickets.
The flight was cancelled while we were at the airport to take the first flight, due to weather.
The cancelation offer was to 'undo' the whole transaction so flights in both directions, so I got the whole amount back, including costs.

There were other offers, rebook to a different flight out for one or both people, refund the flight out but keep the return portion, in case we could make our way there in an other way.

It looks like you now got the offer to keep the one flight so you can book an alternative for the cancelled flight.

Contact the airline and request they either rebook you or refund the whole travel.
This is a routine situation and the usual result is both flights refunded or a new offer for the cancelled flight which include a line how to cancel if not acceptable.